# OpenApi add example for request body

Tags: spring, openapi, swagger-editor, springdoc-openapi-ui

Am working with Spring boot and I am using [springdoc-openapi-ui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui) to generate spec files using [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/)
The issue Is, Am trying to avoid creating model classes just to use them in the request body to show them with swagger UI.
For example :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/project/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> projectUpdate(@RequestBody ObjectNode json, @PathVariable int id)  
    { ... }
```

If I use it like this, the example will be empty on the Swagger UI page.
So as a solution, I have to do it like the following

```
public class CustomerCreateRequest {
    
    @JsonProperty
    private String ProjectId;
    @JsonProperty
    private String ProjectName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String ProjectDescription;
    @JsonProperty
    private String CustomerId;
    @JsonProperty
    private String CustomerName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String CustomerDescription;
    @JsonProperty
    private String BucketId;
    @JsonProperty
    private String API_KEY;
    @JsonProperty
    private String Name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String RedmineId;
```

And then I can use the model class I just created like the following.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createUser")
    public ResponseEntity createCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerCreateRequest requestBody)
    { ... }
```

**Question**

- Is it ok to do a model class just for this purpose?
- Is there a way to add an example so the UI team will have an idea of how to use it.
- I know that a model class can be helpful in generating a client for UI ( like JSClient ) But is it really necessary? I mean can't we overcome this issue?

Any Answer, Suggestion, Links are appreciated, the [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) was not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

my two cents:

> Is it ok to do a model class just for this purpose?

Yes, you should use a model class for your @RequestBody becouse every endpoint must have a contract to communicate the payload necessary to be consumed.
It's a good practice add the annotations like

```
@Parameter(description="Some description", example="{\"foo\":\"bar\"}")
@RequestBody CustomerCreateRequest requestBody
```

> Is there a way to add an example so the UI team will have an idea of how to use it.

No, Swagger will map a POJO class with decorators such as @Schema and others. ObjectNode has not a valid representation for the use case

> I know that a model class can be helpful in generating a client for UI ( like JSClient ) But is it really necessary? I mean can't we overcome this issue?

Well, in my experience use tools as Swagger have more benefits than cons. It's necessary take care about the constraints related? I think so